# SharePoint 2010 "E-mail a Link" within a page layout

Tags: sharepoint, email, sharepoint-2010, controls, page-layout

I have a question concerning the OOB SharePoint 2010 feature "E-mail a Link" which is displayed on lists/libraries and containing items.

I am developing a type of "Article Page Layout" for a client. At the bottom of the article, they would like to have the ability to rate the article, comment on the article, and send an email to someone containing the link to the article.

For the comments, I used the SharePoint comments social feature that is included with user profiles. For the ratings, I used the SharePoint list/library item ratings feature. I just threw controls for both of these on the page layouts, and it works wonderful.

Now, I need a "E-mail a Link" option. I immediately thought of 3 solutions
1. Use the SharePoint OOB feature "E-mail a Link" and place it on the page layout.
2. Use a custom workflow.
3. Use jQuery.

Obviously, I would like to leverage SharePoint OOB features where possible. I believe it has to be possible to "move" the "E-mail a Link" button from the ribbon to the page layout. The page is still a library item, so it should be able to work.

**Can anyone direct me on how to move the "E-mail a Link" button from the ribbon to the page layout?**

Thank you!

-Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answered this question here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/sharepoint2010general/thread/a934c1ae-b8ec-40bf-ad31-fb7fccdbdacd